# In Github, I want to auto deploy after a pull request

Tags: git, github, webhooks, pull-request

I'd like to use a webhook to perform a `git pull` every time a `pull request` is merged on a specific branch.

My repos always have two main branches: `master` and `dev`. The `dev` branch is always staging and `master` is always production. I want production to be a manual process but I'd like staging to be automated. I've found a few tutorials but they seem to be either incomplete or not not quite what I'm trying to do.

I had looked at this gist https://gist.github.com/oodavid/1809044 and had hoped to do something similar. However the `git pull` command didn't work. So I changed it to `ssh -t -t localhost sudo git pull` based on some SO answers but now it just get `Host key verification failed.` even though I have the deploy key setup just like the link says.

Comment: A git pull? Are you running your application out of a local git repo of the github one?

Comment: Create a jenkins/hudson job that will poll for every 'X' minutes and if they are any new changes, it will deploy. There are multiple plugins to help you on this.

Comment: Right now when there is an update to the branch I SSH into our server and perform a `git pull` command on the staging location. I just want to automate that.

Comment: Firstly, setup a [post-receive deployment hook](http://ryanflorence.com/deploying-websites-with-a-tiny-git-hook/) in your local repository on the production server, and then setup a [github webhook](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/) to push whenever a pull request is merged.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII - My repos are already setup and cloned. I'm trying to add this to a current setup. I tried using: https://gist.github.com/oodavid/1809044 but these steps don't quite work and give errors so it' obviously dated. I was hoping to do something like that though.

Comment: @Gangaraju - I've updated the question to show what I've tried and would like to do